# How to force GCC to produce a unique symbol in the static library using C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I am looking for a way to produce UNIQUE symbols in the static library from C++. Use-case : I want to test this library in some environment having dlclose() and make sure that the infrastructure will not break.

Comment: Would using internal linkage work?

Comment: You'll either have to use macros, or a script that will generate C++ code for you.